# Using a transcription pedal as an audio control surface

Tags: hardware, drivers, osc

I just bought an Infinity In-USB-2 foot pedal that's used by transcription software. It was cheap at a consignment store, so I thought I could use it for a fun project. It just hooks up through USB and has two pedals. I'd like to try and use it as an audio control surface for Reaper. So I'm wondering how to approach this. Would it be a matter or writing drivers, writing software, or maybe doing something with OSC?

Answer (score 1):

What does output? You may find it's easier to convert the key commands with something like autohotkey than (good god) developing drivers yourself for a mysterious peice of hardware.

Comment: I'll have to take a look at autohotkey. I'm not really sure how to check what sort of output it has.